# Javascript Do Until Double the Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, while-loop

I've been working on this for hours and somehow cannot solve it. Tried to search on web in tons of different keywords but nothing.

I think it's simple but i can't figure it out, i just can't.

I have a div that increases the amount of value when clicked.

What's happening ALREADY in my code is;
When i click the .button, it adds +10 to value of VALUE div.

```
<div class="button">click me +10</div> 

<div class="value">10</div>
```

When you click to .button; it changes the .value div's content to 20(adds 10)
This is already done on scripting.

What i'm trying to do with Javascript NOW is click to button untill make it double of existing amount.

What i'm trying to do is, get the number on innerHtml and click my +10 button untill get the double of it's value. Let me explain it with my **WRONG** codestring.

HTML Content;

```
<div class="value">10</div>
```

Javascript;

```
var i = parseInt($('.value').html());
var iz = i * 2;
while (i > iz) {

   $('.div').click();

}
```

Tried it with many other ways, like;

```
var i = $('.value').html();
var iz = i * 2;
do {
$('.div').click();
} while (i == iz);
```

Please help me solve it. What i need is doing something(clicking the button for example) untill it hits the double of current amount written in HTML content. Basically multiply it. I know how to do that math but it doesn't work with While command.

**Remember IT'S HTML CONTENT, NOT INPUT. AND I CAN'T CHANGE IT TO INPUT**

Thanks.

**BIG BOLD EDIT:**
Sorry for the misunderstood. Let me explain all the things i'm doing **already** and i want to do **now**.

I have a div that increases the amount of value when clicked.

What's happening ALREADY in my code is;
When i click the .button, it adds +10 to value of VALUE div.

```
<div class="button">click me +10</div> 

<div class="value">10</div>
```

When you click to .button; it changes the .value div's content to 20(adds 10)
This is already done on scripting.

What i'm trying to do with Javascript NOW is click to button untill make it double of existing amount. No matter how :)

Comment: What is the `.button` that you are trying to click? Why are you trying to click a button at all? Your `while (i > iz)` test will always be false, because `i` is `"10"` and `iz` is `20`.

Comment: I'm trying to make some kind of robot that will trigger the DIV's click event. Basically. I don't know if this question have anything to do about my problem. For your edit: How can i make it stable for doing it's job on the script then? Don't know how to explain that but this is what exactly i need. My profession is ASP but i think ASP and Javascript is not using the same logic at all.

Comment: Nothing in the code shown causes the `.value` element to change or updates the `i` or `iz` variables after they're assigned values initially, so the `while` conditions in both blocks will always be false. If there is a click handler on `.button` you need to [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what it is you are trying to do as well as provide all relevant html

Comment: Click the button until i == iz, you need to increment i, and you haven't done that, so I don't see how "i" could ever equal "iz".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a click, this is not what you need:

```
$('.div').click();
```

because `click()` is suposed to use when you want to handle a click event.

Instead use this:

```
$('.div')[0].click();
```

There you are getting the DOM element and clicking it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0];
var i = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
var iz = parseInt(i,10) * 2;
 div.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(i,10) + 1;
  if (i<iz-1){
   i++;
  }
 });
```

```html
<div class="clickme" id = "value" >
10
</div>
```

Edited my answer to allow single increment of original value until it is doubled. Your question was quiet hard to understand (language barriers), none the less, I hope this helps.

**EDIT TO ADD**

If you want to increment the div value until it reaches double (automatically), you can do this:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0];
var i = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
var iz = parseInt(i,10) * 2;

 window.setInterval(function() {
 if (i<iz){
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = parseInt(i,10) + 1;
  
   i++;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="clickme" id = "value" >
10
</div>
```

Comment: I'm already doing that part adds amount when div is clicked :)

You have a div, <div class="value">10</div>
You have a another div, as a button. <div class="imabutton">+10</div>

When you click to .imabutton; value changes to 20, when you click again, it changes to 30 and it goes on...

Which is DONE. I'm asking how to use Javascript to click automatically to button untill find the DOUBLE of existing amount.